# How to turn a python variable into lower case?

Tags: python

I would like to turn everything into a lowercase but no matter what i try it always brings back "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'" what am i doing wrong?

```
user_input = input("")
    prohibited = {'this','although','and','as','because','but','even if','he','and','however','an','a','is','what','question :','question','[',']',',','cosmos',' ','  ','   ','cosmo'}
    tokens = [word for word in re.split("\W+", user_input) if word.lower() not in prohibited]
    tokens.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    words = str(tokens).split()
    TokenCount = len(words)
    tokens = tokens.lower()
```

Comment: `lower` is a string method.  `tokens` is a list of strings.

Comment: yes.. is there a way around that?

Comment: you can use map to use the lower for every element in list

Comment: `tokens=list(map(lambda x:x.lower(),tokens))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a lambda expression to map the str.lower() calls to elements of list. Instead of your last line, try this:

```
tokens = list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), tokens))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a one line for loop:

```
tokens = [t.lower() for t in tokens]
```

This applies the string operation 'lower()' to each element of the list and then compiles them again into a list (the [] brackets).